# How do I return an occurances count from a column and multiply those values to another column of values?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I would like to take the df below, group unique values together by 'USER','TASK', and 'STATIC_VALUE'.  I can do this using groupby(), but I'm having trouble adding a 'TASK_COUNT' and a 'TOTALS' column.  The 'TOTALS' column would be multiplying 'STATIC_VALUE' * 'TASK_COUNT'.  I've tried a number of variations of groupby(), transform(), size() and I can't get there. Suggestions?  Thank you!

**Dataframe:**

```
    USER    TASK    STATIC_VALUE
1   USER1   TASK2   30
2   USER2   TASK7   12  
3   USER5   TASK4   9
4   USER12  TASK2   30
5   USER2   TASK3   10
6   USER1   TASK2   30
7   USER5   TASK7   12
8   USER1   TASK3   10
9   USER2   TASK3   10
```

This piece gets me close:

```
>>> df.groupby(['USER','TASK','STATIC_VALUE']).size()

USER    TASK    STATIC_VALUE    
USER1   TASK2   30              2
        TASK3   10              1
USER2   TASK7   12              1
        TASK3   10              2
USER5   TASK4   9               1
        TASK7   12              1
USER12  TASK2   30              1
```

**Expected Result:**

```
USER    TASK    STATIC_VALUE    TASK_COUNT  TOTAL
USER1   TASK2   30              2           60
        TASK3   10              1           10
USER2   TASK7   12              1           12
        TASK3   10              2           20
USER5   TASK4   9               1           9
        TASK7   12              1           12
USER12  TASK2   30              1           30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['USER','TASK', 'STATIC_VALUE']).size().reset_index(name='TASK_COUNT')
df1['TOTAL'] = df1['TASK_COUNT'] * df1['STATIC_VALUE']
print (df1)
     USER   TASK  STATIC_VALUE  TASK_COUNT  TOTAL
0   USER1  TASK2            30           2     60
1   USER1  TASK3            10           1     10
2  USER12  TASK2            30           1     30
3   USER2  TASK3            10           2     20
4   USER2  TASK7            12           1     12
5   USER5  TASK4             9           1      9
6   USER5  TASK7            12           1     12
```

Comment: That's it!  Thank you so much!  Although, frustrating to know I was so close to figuring it out on my own...lol :)

Comment: Glad can help you!